# Receiving a 4 to 20mA signal with R Click board

Tags: signal, current-measurement

I have [this sensor](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/pressure-sensors/4554624/) that is supplied with 12V and gives out a 4 to 20mA signal.

Would [this 4 to 20ma](https://www.mikroe.com/4-20ma-r-click) receiving board be capable of reading the signal? I wasnt sure if the 12V would blow the board.

Answer (score 1):

> Would this 4 to 20ma receiving board be capable of reading the signal?
>   I wasnt sure if the 12V would blow the board.

The circuitry for your 4/20 mA receiver is shown here with specific attention to the nodes with a purple box: -

[image]

If you look closely it shows that the 4/20 mA signal gets shunted by a 4.99 ohm resistor connected to an internal 16 volt supply. So if 20 mA is flowing from that node it drops 99.8 mV and this means that the monitor chip (INA196) sees inputs of: -

- Vin+ = 16 volts
- Vin- = 15.9002 volts

As you can see, there is 16 volts anyway and the circuit supposedly works fine at these levels. Additionally, the INA196 has a common mode input range from -16 volts to +80 volts so this should dispel any worries about damaging the monitor.

However, I'd be concerned about two things regarding your sensor: -

- Is the output of the sensor going to get damaged by the 16 volts produced by the monitor - if so then run your sensor from +24 volts (for convenience AND fine-tooth pick the data sheet.
- Is the output of the sensor galvanically isolated from it's supply. Preferably it needs to be unless you take very good care of isolating the 4/20 mA receiver.

Double check the sensor data sheet is my strong advice.